# Is there a way to deserialize json object when using dynamic in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I have a graphql executioner code that looks like this:

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteGQlQuery<T>(string url, string reqQuery, AuthenticationHeaderValue credentials, object variables)
{
    try
    {
        var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(url, new SystemTextJsonSerializer());
        graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = credentials;

        var gQLRequest = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = reqQuery,
            Variables = variables
        };

        var response = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<T>(gQLRequest);

        return response.Data;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I send in a specific type that I want the data to be converted to.

I have a scenario where I want to fetch data and what ever I get back I just want to forward it to the frontend without converting it to an object type so I used `dynamic`:

```
var data = await _executeService.ExecuteGQlQuery<dynamic>(myUrl, query, credentials, null);
```

I can see the json data but when I see the return I see

```
{"ValueKind":"Object"}
```

Is there a way to deserialize this correctly and what am I missing?

Comment: you can simply return `string` instead of `dynamic`

Comment: No you cannot - the deserializer does not understand how to deal with a String, and throws an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this took me a while and a few attempts.

I never  considered that my `GraphQLHttpClient` settings were off since I was using `SystemTextJsonSerializer`

I added the `GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft` nuget package and changed from `SystemTextJsonSerializer` to `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer`

And it works now.

Also note that if you have a service in say a class library you will need to add
`GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft` nuget package into your source project to get this working.